Interacting Programmatically with a Spline 3D Scene in SwiftUI (iOS)
I'm new to the Spline 3D framework and I'm wondering if it's possible to interact programmatically with a Spline 3D scene in a SwiftUI environment on iOS. Specifically, I would like to:

Change the values of spline variables.
Listen for changes in the values of these variables.
List item

I've searched through the documentation but couldn't find any relevant information on these features.
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help.

Please check https://medium.com/@aniketbaneani/creating-dynamic-3d-content-for-ios-with-spline-c5612f91b3c4

That's not what I'm looking for, I want to change variable value inside Spline from SwiftUI

You can't for now, I asked them on their discord. All you can do is loading a 3d scenes/objects at the moment with some basic interactions, nothing customizable with code at the moment
